# Why don't some people get bruises?

Tags: pain, bruising-bruise

I know some people bruise very easily, Example I poked a person on the side very lightly and the next day it looks like someone punched them in the side.
For me yesterday I was balancing on a log, I slipped and fell on my hip, it really does hurt and it looks like a big bruise should be there, but there is no bruise there. It is not even red. I have other times where I should have bruised but didn't.(I am not trying to bruise myself so I can get a bruise, I am just curious. )

Why am I not bruising? As in is it Genetic or because my body is used to falling down? (since I am kind of clumsy)

Comment: People with coagulopqthy get bruises easily, so I suspect it has something to do with blood clotting.

Comment: Skin tone is also going to play a role. Bruises will be more readily visible on a person with fair skin than a person with dark skin.